# is there a shortcut to know, when I'm running my app, which view controller am I in?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2

I'm working on an application that already exists, and I want to run the app and know in the output which view controller am I in, without going to every class and viewController and printing its name. Is there a shortcut or something that can help me ??

I've tried printing in view did load in every ViewController

like

```
print("view did load : MainViewController")
```

but I found this wasting of time because I have so many viewControllers.
I think about debugging but I really don't know what it does or how.

Comment: You could also subclass `UIViewController` and override the `viewDidLoad` method. But then you'd have to change all your view controllers to that custom vc.

Comment: With respect, a few "warning alarms" are going off reading your question. Why "som many viewControllers"? This seems like a design issue. (I'd prefer hearing so "many views" instead. At which point the question of "which view was used" is much easier.) Typically, unless you have "so many **child** viewControllers" you really have one - root - VC. Again, this seems to be a design issue. Finally Why do you need to know this? (And yes, again, this seems to me to be a design issue. Any chance you could provide more details? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could swizzle (exchange the implementation of) `UIViewController.viewDidAppear` so it prints the class name.  First define your swizzled implementation:

```
extension UIViewController {
    @objc func printingViewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print(String(describing: type(of: self)))

        // Call the original implementation.  This looks like recursion but isn't
        printingViewDidAppear(animated)
    }
}
```

Then exchange the default implementation with your implementation like this:

```
let originalViewDidAppear: Method = class_getInstanceMethod(UIViewController.self, #selector(UIViewController.viewDidAppear(_:)))!

let swizzledViewDidAppear: Method = class_getInstanceMethod(UIViewController.self, #selector(UIViewController.printingViewDidAppear(_:)))!

method_exchangeImplementations(originalViewDidAppear, swizzledViewDidAppear)
```

That way you wouldn't need to change any of your existing view controllers.

You must make sure to call the original implementation at the end of the swizzled implementation.  It looks like a recursive call but it isn't.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is possible. What you can do, however, to make it a little simpler, is adding this extension to `UIViewController`:

```
extension UIViewController {
    var className: String {
        return String(describing: type(of: self))
    }
}
```

Then, in `viewDidLoad`, print it:

```
print("loaded \(self.className)")
```

Comment: yeah but still the same, i need to go to each viewController and write this code.
I want something that can save all this. and maybe even print me the function. i want to know everystep that i'm making with the app in the code

Comment: Yes, but you could do it via code replacement and then do that by batch. So find `super.viewDidLoad()` and replace it with `super.viewDidLoad(); print(self.className)`. Then press *replace all*. Not ideal, but works 

Comment: i'm sorry but i'm searching for another solution, that can help me to save the time. I've already said that I know this solution, but i'm searching for another. thank you anyway

Comment: You can get back to this one if there's no better :)